# launchctl status returns 2

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I'm trying to write a `launchd` script that will run a Python script every hour.

I created the following file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`

**com.b00tahead.engage-check.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.b00tahead.engage-check</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3</string>
        <string>Projects/engage_scripts/engage_check.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>3600</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I then run:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.b00tahead.engage-check.plist
launchctl start com.b00tahead.engage-check
```

When I run `launchctl list` it shows the process as:

```
PID Status  Label
-   2       com.b00tahead.engage-check
```

I'm not exactly sure what that return code indicates. I can run the script just fine through the terminal as `python3 Projects/engage_scripts/engage_check.py`

The Python script writes some data to a .txt file on my desktop.

This is what `launchctl list com.b00tahead.engage-check` returns:

```
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
    "Label" = "com.b00tahead.engage-check";
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "OnDemand" = true;
    "LastExitStatus" = 512;
    "Program" = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3";
        "Projects/engage_scripts/engage_check.py";
    );
};
```

Comment: If the script ran successfully it would usually return a status `0`. You can likely glean a little more info about what is going on by using the command `launchctl list com.b00tahead.engage-check`

Comment: Updated with results from `launchctl list com.b00tahead.engage-check`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the argument in `ProgramArguments` should have an absolute path (not relative such as `Projects/...`).

In case of error, system log should be checked, e.g.

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

or custom log can be used by specifying these lines:

```
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/var/log/myjob.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/var/log/myjob.log</string>
```

See: [Debugging launchd Jobs section of Creating Launch Daemons and Agents page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW7-BCIEDDBJ).